# ListView adapter and ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, string, listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

first I am a programming noob and I wanted to do something like taking the user when he/she select Clear_data and it will take the person to Clear_data activity.

I am running in to a problem with try and catch, as I am still a bit lost in general programming. As I testing it when I select the first choice which is Text_Colour and it opens up the Clear_data activity instead of Text_Colour.

Here is the code:

```
public class Settings extends ListActivity {


String classes[] = { "Text_Colour", "Clear_data", "Contact Developer" };


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Settings.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String colours = classes[0];
    String cdata = classes[1];

    try {
    Class Class1 = Class.forName("com.example.test1." + colours);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Settings.this, Class1);
    startActivity(intent1);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
    Class Class2 = Class.forName("com.example.test1." + cdata);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Settings.this, Class2);
    startActivity(intent2);
    } 
    catch(ClassNotFoundException d) {
        d.printStackTrace();
    }   

}
```

Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sholud probably add a switch operator like this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String colours = classes[0];
    String cdata = classes[1];

switch(position){
case 0:
    try {
    Class Class1 = Class.forName("com.example.test1." + colours);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Settings.this, Class1);
    startActivity(intent1);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
break;
case 1:
    try {
    Class Class2 = Class.forName("com.example.test1." + cdata);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Settings.this, Class2);
    startActivity(intent2);
    } 
    catch(ClassNotFoundException d) {
        d.printStackTrace();
    }   
break;
}

}
```

Comment: @Ket You're always welcome. Pls accept the answer if it helped ;)